# Increase power output of squirrel cage induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor

I have a squirrel cage induction motor rated at 15 kW, 415 V 50 Hz, 1460 rpm. I want to increase its power above 20 kW.

I am going to rewind the same motor for 3000 rpm, at 250 Hz supply frequency, keeping the same magnetic field (average air gap field) at this higher frequency.

If I use conductors of a higher current rating, will I be able to achieve this higher power?

Comment: Are you writing your question using a mobile device?

Comment: A 1/3 increase in power would produce more heat than the it was designed for, and I agree with the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I work with robotics and power to weight ratios are a problem. I have frequently rewound motors to run them at higher frequencies and power - getting 15kW our of a 3kw motor and 24kw out of a 3kw motor by running them at 250Hz and 400Hz respectively.

These have been running 10 years.

I just recently wound a 300W single phase to three phase and run it at 12000 rpm. - 1200W out of a very small frame size motor.

The caution that the rotor might explode is a wise one but the smaller the motor the more you can get away with.

I would be more and more circumspect as the size of the motor increases.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of a three phase induction motor is determined by the number of poles and the operating frequency: -

Synchronous Speed = \$\dfrac{2\times 60\times F}{N}\$ where F = frequency and N is number of poles.

The motor in the question has four poles based on the operating frequency stated. They don't run at synchronous speed but slightly less in order to actually induce current in the rotor. A synchronous motor has DC applied to the rotor and it will run at exactly 1500rpm but an induction motor relies on induction and of course you can't induce DC magnetically.

If you ran it at 250Hz (without alteration) you might expect speed to increase 5 times to 7,500 rpm so, can you rewind the motor to make it run at 3,000 rpm at 250Hz? No, I don't think so.

If you decided to run it at 100Hz (3,000 rpm) would you get problems? Almost certainly - it's designed to run at 1500 rpm and doubling the speed puts a 4x centrifugal force on the rotor windings and they would likely fall apart - why would a motor manufacturer build this extra capacity into a motor?

Centrifugal force = \$ mass\times radius (2 π n / 60)^2\$ where n is rotational speed in revs per minute.

You can see that the outward force is proportional to rpm squared i.e. double the speed and you quadruple the forces acting on the squirrel cage windings.

Also, the squirrel cage rotor winding is designed to produce optimum magnetic field properties at the slip frequency on full load on a 50Hz supply.

No this is an unwise thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, why would they make different rotors for two/four/six/eight pole stators? 3000rpm is two pole 50Hz, two pole 60Hz means 3600rpm (ignoring slip). Hardly a concern.

An eight pole winding would give 3000rpm at about 250Hz (taking slip into account), so I don't see anything principally wrong with the idea.

Allthough, increased power would benefit from extra back iron, so might be better to start with a two pole stator (as these usually have more iron to begin with, due to the larger and stronger rotating pole) before rewinding.